# Java public field accessible in debugger but not in Kotlin code

Tags: android, kotlin, field, android-studio-debugger

Why the following public field of the class `android.util.DisplayMetrics`:

```
public float noncompatDensity;
```

is visible in the debugger:

[image: Android studio debugger]

but not available in code?

[image: Android studio code]

I'm using Android Studio Bumblebee | 2021.1.1 Patch 3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you look in the source you can see this:

```
/**
 * The reported scaled density prior to any compatibility mode scaling
 * being applied.
 * @hide
 */
public float noncompatScaledDensity;
```

It's annotated with `@hide` which means the field is not technically part of the SDK.  Google uses the @hide annotation to strip out the classes and methods they don't want to be part of the public SDK. That's why your IDE cannot compile your code against them -- they literally don't exist. However, the android framework jar on an actual device DOES contain these classes and methods, which is why they can be accessed at runtime using reflection.